# PostgreSQL: Getting <NULL> string by passing null value to function

Tags: postgresql

I have the following function with one parameter. I need to display a string which consist `select` statement and `where` condition.

**Example**:

```
create or replace function funct(a int)
returns void as
$$
declare
       wrclause varchar := '';
       sqlq varchar ;
       t varchar;
begin
       wrclause := ' AND C IN ('|| a || ')';

       sqlq := ' t :=select string_agg(''select *, abcd as "D" from '' || table_namess  ||, '' Union all '') as namess
        from tablescollection2 ud
        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables so on ud.table_namess = so.Table_name where C = '|| a ||'' || wrclause;

       raise info '%',sqlq;

       perform sqlq;

       raise info '%',t;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

**Calling Function**:  With value 1

```
select funct(1);
```

**Output**:

```
INFO:   t :=select string_agg('select *, abcd as "D" from ' || table_namess ||, ' Union all ') as namess
        from tablescollection2 ud
        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables so on ud.table_namess = so.Table_name where C = 1 AND C IN (1)
INFO:  <NULL>
```

**Calling Function**: With null value

```
select funct(null);
```

**Output**:

```
INFO:  <NULL>
INFO:  <NULL>
```

**Note**: I am not getting after assigning empty string to `wrclause` variable why I am getting `<NULL>` string and also `<NULL>` to variable `t`.

Comment: Any string concatenated with `NULL` will result in `NULL`, just as any number added to `NULL` will result in `NULL`, and any boolean expression such as `AND NULL` or `OR NULL` will evaluate to `NULL`.

Comment: @IMSoP, If I have `null` values to pass then what is the solution for this? Thanks

Comment: @IMSoP, In SQL Server we can do this by using `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF`. How about PostgreSQL?

Comment: what should be query if a = NULL ?

Comment: @Meem Rather than looking for a way to disable standard behaviour, just handle the nulls properly; if you want an empty string for null, `COALESCE(var, '')` is the simplest; but in this case that would result in invalid SQL anyway (`AND C IN ()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try something like below if it satisfied your all meets for NULL as well:

```
create or replace function funct(a int)
returns void as
$$
declare
       wrclause varchar := '';
       sqlq varchar ;
       t varchar;
begin
    IF (a IS NOT NULL ) THEN 
        wrclause := 'where C = '|| a ||' AND C IN ('|| a || ')';
    END IF;


       sqlq := ' t :=select string_agg(''select *, abcd as "D" from '' || table_namess  ||, '' Union all '') as namess
        from tablescollection2 ud
        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables so on ud.table_namess = so.Table_name ' || wrclause;

       raise info '%',sqlq;

       perform sqlq;

       raise info '%',t;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

select funct(1);
```

OUTPUT:

```
INFO:   t :=select string_agg('select *, abcd as "D" from ' || table_namess  ||, ' Union all ') as namess
        from tablescollection2 ud
        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables so on ud.table_namess = so.Table_name where C = 1 AND C IN (1)
INFO:  <NULL>

select funct(null)

INFO:   t :=select string_agg('select *, abcd as "D" from ' || table_namess  ||, ' Union all ') as namess
        from tablescollection2 ud
        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables so on ud.table_namess = so.Table_name
INFO:  <NULL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more confusion here: what about variable `t`? It need to show `select` statement result.

Comment: where is the value of variable: table_namess ?

Comment: That is the `column` name which I will get from `table` "tablescollection2".